# Angular parameters only work on a subfolder, not on root level

Tags: angular

I have an issue with using parameters - they only work on a sub-folder.

When I test my code on localhost:1234 then the ID does not work.
When running it on the server, it works in a sub-folder, meaning this will work:
[www.somewhere.com/development/signin/1234](http://www.somewhere.com/development/signin/1234)
but this will not work
[www.somewhere.com/signin/1234](http://www.somewhere.com/signin/1234)

I have 2 of these in my system, and both act the same. When opened from within the code, it works, but having it as a link on an email or just entering the address manually, it will not work.
Only when using a subfolder such as /development it will work.

This is easy to replicate - in any system, go to the point, where you open an item with an ID - e.g. viewitem/1234 - once open press ctrl+f5. In my case angular stops working and the page goes blank

Why is this?

The hole file is:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'signin/:id',
    component: SigninComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Login',
      subtitle: ''
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'signin',
    component: SigninComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Login',
      subtitle: ''
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainPageComponent,
    canActivate: [SigninGuard],
    data: {
      title: 'Main page',
      subtitle: ''
    }
  },  
  {
    path: 'item/:id',
    canActivate: [SigninGuard],
    component: DetailsComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'ItemDetails',
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'report',
    component: ReportComponent,
    canActivate: [SigninGuard],
    data: {
      title: 'Status Report',
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/main',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent,
    data: { title: '404' }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {initialNavigation: true})
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Is this all you have on your routes file? Can you share more of your project's app component and routes file?

Comment: You need to show your **server configurations**. Does it at least point to `index.html`? The implementation of course depends on your backend

Comment: I included the full code.
Yes the index works, as the system works, going to www.myplace.com and it opens. Selecting an item and route(/item, ID) works as well.
It all works in the subfolder, my development folder. Only when running local on my computer or main folder then will just give a blank scree.
I have added Alert()'s in places to see what happens, and it is really just stops - like it cannot open any page at all. Debugging locally and console output also just stops.

Comment: How does   <base href="./"> and base path affect this?

Comment: @sonnich `base href` will resolve URLs in your app with its value, if you have an additional string in base href that will get appended on your routes and likely won't match if you navigate to a route that doesn't include that string https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag